# Mail filtering with procmail in a postfix/dovecot system with virtual users

Tags: email, postfix, filter, dovecot, procmail

I had a postfix/dovecot system with mail users working. After unsuccessfully following a few tutorials online to enable procmail, now I have an unusable system.

What I want is  to enable procmail filtering for my user paulo @ mydomain.com :

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = centauri.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = centauri.mydomain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
message_size_limit = 40720000
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

# Configuring submission port for auth through dovecot
# http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_sasl_enable
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

# -----

broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
#virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
#virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
#virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_transport = virtual
#transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
#content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf**

```
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
         -o content_filter=
         -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
procmail  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=RO user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/procmail -t -m USER=${user} EXTENSION=${extension} DOMAIN=${domain} /etc/postfix/procmailrc.common
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
postfixfilter unix - n n - - pipe
       flags=Rq user=vmail argv=/etc/postfix/spamfilter -f ${sender} -- ${recipient}
# Options for the filter
#smtp-amavis     unix    -       -       -       -       2       smtp
#        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
#        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
#        -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
#        -o max_use=20

# Listener for filtered mail
127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
        -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
        -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
        -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
        -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
        -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
        -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

**/etc/postfix/procmailrc.common**

```
SHELL="/bin/bash"
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t"
LOGFILE="/var/log/procmail.log"
DELIVER=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
# fallback:
DEFAULT="$HOME/Maildir/"
MAILDIR="$HOME/Maildir/"
:0 w
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
| $DELIVER -m spam
:0 w
| $DELIVER
```

Why is it that when I send an email to my self procmail.log is not even created. It seems mails currently just getting lost since not even dovecot is picking it up.

Comment: I don't have much `postfix` knowledge -- I invoke `procmail` *after* the mail recipient has been determined (either by `sendmail` or `fetchmail`).  As a result, my procmail always runs as the recipient user.  So for me specifying the LOGFILE path inside /var/log would result in a permissions error.  Could that be the reason why your procmail log is not being created?

Answer (score 4):

Your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file doesn't mention procmail anywhere. This is the problem, AFAIK.

In my case, I have:

```
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

and my procmail config file is in `~user/.procmailrc`. However this is a real user on the machine. It seems that you're using virtual transport, in which case I suppose that you should use something like:

```
virtual_transport = procmail
procmail_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

(all users will be concerned, but your procmail rules can deal with that, or you may want to use [transport_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) with a [transport table](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)). I suppose that you can more or less copy from the [Postfix + Maildrop Howto](http://www.postfix.org/MAILDROP_README.html), replacing `maildrop` by `procmail`.

Alternatively, I wonder whether you can use something based on:

```
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

/etc/postfix/virtual:
  paulo@mydomain.com procmail

/etc/aliases:
  procmail: "|/path/to/procmail ..."
```

Comment: How would you achieve the same without Procmail? Even author is pleading to Linux distros for not to package Procmail anymore and users to stop distributing and using.

Comment: @JariTurkia From the postfix point of view, you can use any mail delivery agent in a similar way, with the same syntax. The only thing that potentially changes is the arguments and the configuration file of the mail delivery agent. The `postconf(5)` man page gives some examples, such as `mailbox_command = /some/where/maildrop -d "$USER" -f "$SENDER" "$EXTENSION"`.