# how to use procmail as a MDA for postfix? (mailbox_command)

Tags: postfix, procmail

I am trying to setup procmail as a mail delivery agent (MDA) for postfix.  I understand that I should use the `mailbox_command` option in postfix for this, but an internet search revealed contradicting advice on how exactly to do this:

- Several sources suggest to just use

  ```
  mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail
  ```

  Examples can be found [here](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/focus_spam_dspam/) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148095/23046).
- Some sources suggest using the `-f` option, *e.g.* as in

  ```
  mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -f-
  ```

  See for example [here](http://traxel.com/doc/spamassassin-setup.html).  This seems to adjust the date in From lines.
- Some sources suggest using procmail in "delivery mode", *i.e.* using the `-d` option:

  ```
  mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -d ${USER}
  ```

  See for example [here](http://www.mhonarc.org/archive/html/procmail/2006-11/msg00010.html) and [here](http://procmail.rwth-aachen.narkive.com/JoPgKnBq/postfix-procmail-courier-imap-master-cf-owner).

(There are many variations of these three approaches, *e.g.* using `-a` to pass information to the procmail recipes or setting `MAILDIR`.)

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the three approaches?  And in particular, what is the effect of using "delivery mode"?

Comment: `-d` is for when Procmail is invoked as root; but with `mailbox_command`, it won't be -- Postfix will already run it with the recipient's UID and GID.  Similarly, `-f-` is probably not necessary with Postfix, as there should not be a `From_` line on the incoming message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postfix executes `mailbox_command` with [uid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier_%28Unix%29) of the recipient.  It should make `-d ${USER}` unnecessary.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_command

> **mailbox_command (default: empty)**
>   Optional external command that the local(8) delivery agent should use for mailbox delivery. The command is run with the user ID and the primary group ID privileges of the recipient. Exception: command delivery for root executes with $default_privs privileges.